# java mysqldump with where option

Tags: java, mysql, linux

I try to use this code, which works on linux command line, under java

`mysqldump --where="date>='20180201' AND date<='20180228'" -uuser -ppassword --skip-add-drop-table --no-create-info --no-create-db  -B mydb  --tables table1 -r /root/Documents/DbBackup/table1.sql`

To make it work in java, I use the following code:

```
public static boolean backupDB(String dbName, String where_filter, String path, String tableName) {
    String executeCmd = "mysqldump --where="+where_filter+" -u" + userName + " -p" + password + " --skip-add-drop-table --no-create-info --no-create-db "+" -B " + dbName +" "+tableName+" -r " + path;

    System.out.println("backupDB "+executeCmd);
    Process runtimeProcess;
    try {

        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Backup created successfully");

            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not create the backup");                
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {            

    }

    return false;
}
```

The same command line instruction does not work if the invocation is inside the java code. Where am I wrong? is it possible to redirect an error log to a file?

If I use as where clause`--where=date='20180206'` it works also under java.

Comment: Per your last question, you can redirect a log to a file using `2> output.log` as a `mysqldump` parameter.

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov It works on command line, but not in my java code

Comment: And I assume that `System.out.println` prints the EXACT same command, right?

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov Yes

Comment: in `+ dbName +" "+tableName+" -r "` does the `tableName` parameter contains `--table` argument before table name `table1`?. or it must be `+ dbName +" ` **--tables** `" +tableName+" -r "`

Comment: @user12043 the tableName parameter contains " --tables table1"

Comment: hmm. you can add `>~/Desktop/output.log` at the end of the command to redirect the output to a file. Like this:
`String executeCmd = "mysqldump --where="+where_filter+" -u" + userName + " -p" + password + " --skip-add-drop-table --no-create-info --no-create-db "+" -B " + dbName +" "+tableName+" -r " + path + ">~/Desktop/output.log";
`

Comment: and try to write `mysqldump` command with full path. for example`/usr/bin/mysqld ...`

Comment: Please try to write your `where_clause` as `--where='where_condition', -w 'where_condition'` instead of `--where="'where_condition' AND 'where_condition'"` according to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many arguments in the command. I think you should use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec`. It takes the command and arguments as an array and this way is safer IMHO. So try this code:

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[]{
    "mysqldump", "--where=" + where_filter, "-u" + userName, "-p" + password, 
    "--skip-add-drop-table", "--no-create-info", "--no-create-db", "-B", dbName, 
    "--tables", tableName, "--result-file=" + path
};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(executeCmd);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process runtimeProcess;
try {

    runtimeProcess = builder.start();
    InputStream processInputStream = process.getInputStream();
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
    if (processComplete == 0) {
        System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not create the backup");                
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(processInputStream));
    System.out.println("output: ");
        while (reader.ready()) {
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        }
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
return false;
```

Also try to write the `mysqldump` command with full path like `/usr/bin/mysqldump` if works with this, then the `mysqldump` command is not in the path.

Comment: I have tried your code, but it doens't resolve the problem !

Comment: @famedoro have you redirected the output of the command to see?

Comment: @No, I tried 2> error.log, but it does not work (in java code), also the previous code worked if I used --where=date='20180206' and not --where="date>='20180201' AND date<='20180228'", but it does not work with your code

Comment: @famedoro I edited the answer to print the output. Please try again

Comment: Who is process object ? runtimeProcess !

Comment: @famedoro Yes, the `builder.start()` function returns the started `Process` instance

Comment: output: 
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect. But the user/passwd that I use is user and password and not root etc..

Comment: I have correct your executeCmd  array in String[] executeCmd = new String[]{
            "mysqldump", "--where="+where_filter, 
            "-u"+userName, "-p"+password, "--skip-add-drop-table", "--no-create-info", 
            "--no-create-db", "-B", dbName, "--tables", tableName,  "--result-file="+path} the problem was due to the way in which parameters are passed and to the spaces that separate them, thanks for your help